# Jest Mocking - Simple Mock

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

Jest mocking is really confusing me right now.

I have the following code in my notifications.js module:

```
// Dispatch notifications to MQTT end point
function dispatcher(shipment) {
  mqttclient.publish('notification', JSON.stringify(shipment));
  return console.info('Notification dispatched.');
}
```

I export this so it is available for my tests:

```
module.exports = { notificationProcessor, notificationDispatch, dispatcher };
```

I wish to change the implementation of this function during my tests so that the mqqtclient.publish event does not fire.

I have tried to mock the overall mqtt npm module which is also part of that file but it gets quite involved, so I split out the dispatcher function from my main code so I could focus purely on that.

dispatcher is called from notificationProcessor if a notification is identified. In my test file I am simply supplying the notificationProcessor with an email which is parsed and then issued out to the dispatcher.

How do I go about mocking the implementation of this simple function?

Comment: posted an answer but presumably you want to do this because you don't want the mqttclient to publish a notification. in that case, why not mock mqttclient.publish instead?

Comment: Yeap precisely. I tried to mock the .publish but it was a bit beyond my js knowledge right now. I'm using npm mqtt in vanilla format. I can mock .connect but then this is assigned to mqttclient which in turn returns a MqttClient function with prototype .publish

Comment: I think this page explains what I need to do https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html I think I've missed the usage of placing the mock beside the mqtt node_modules folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock it without removing `dispatcher` out of the first module since `dispatcher` was an export.

in `./__mocks__/notifications.js`

```
const notifications = require.requireActual('../notifications.js');

notifications.dispatcher = function(shipment) {
  // mock implementation
}

module.exports = notifications;
```

then in your test, you'd call `jest.mock('path/to/notifications.js')`.

Quite simply, you are telling jest that anytime the `notifications` module is required, require the mock which actually loads the original module with a replaced dispatcher function and send that through.

Now there is a potential caveat ... in doing this, you're only changing the exports object, so it would only work if your `notifications` module calls `dispatcher` via `module.exports.dispatcher`.

---

if instead you don't want to call `module.exports.dispatcher` within your source file, yes you'll have pull `dispatcher` out into it's own module, but mocking it should look fairly similar.

in `./__mocks__/dispatcher.js`

```
module.exports = function dispatcher(shipment) {
  // mock implementation
}
```

and call `jest.mock('path/to/dispatcher.js')` in your test.

Comment: Thanks for this and covering scenario 2.  When you say pull this out into another module do you mean just for the mock or do you mean it's own module overall which of course is then much easier to mock as it's seperate

Comment: Followed scenario 1 and just called via module.exports.dispatcher. Excellent guidance thank you.

Comment: for scenario 2, exactly what you described. it's easier to mock when it's separate.